# What is the direction of the gradient in gradient descent?

Tags: gradient-descent

I understand in the gradient descent optimisation algorithm , in each iteration we need to take a step opposite to the direction of the gradient.
[image]

In the above diagram the direction of the gradient vector is opposite to delta theta?
Can somebody please help me understand this?

Comment: maybe trying to minimize the cost function that's why opposite direction

Comment: but the step has to be taken in the direction of delta theta . so how is it in opposite direction of the gradient?

Comment: In the above diagram, $\Delta \theta$ is a scalar and the gradient at a given point $\theta \in \mathbb R$ is also a scalar. That arrow pointing down and to the left is unhelpful and potentially misleading. If this loss function $f$ has its minimum at $\theta=0$, then $\nabla f(\theta)$ visually points to the right if $\theta$ is positive and points to the left if $\theta$ is negative.

Comment: There are only two directions in $\mathbb{R}$, these are $\pm 1$.